# How to test a Rails Model Class method which calls a method on all members?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

In my Rails 4 project I've got a model, `EventGenerator` with an instance method `generate` (which creates some records in the database), and a class method `generate_all` which is intended to be called by a Rake task and looks something like this:

```rb
def self.generate_all
  all.each(&:generate)
end
```

I can think of several approaches to testing this (I'm using RSpec 3 and Fabrication):

1. Don't bother - it's too simple to require tests. DHH says ["Don't aim for 100% coverage"](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3159-testing-like-the-tsa). On the other hand, this is going to be called by a rake task, so won't be regularly exercised: I feel like that's a good reason to have tests.
2. Create a couple of `EventGenerator` instances in the database and use `any_instance.should_receive(:generate)` as the assertion - but [RSpec 3 now recommends against this](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/old-syntax/any-instance) and requires a fudge to make it work. This is a personal 'showcase project' so if possible I'd like everything to be best-practice. Also (DHH aside) shouldn't it still be possible to create fast model specs which don't touch the database?
3. Like 2, but stub out `EventGenerator.all` to return some instances without touching the database. But stubbing the class under test is bad, right? And fragile.
4. Don't worry about unit testing it and instead cover it with an integration test: create a couple of generators in the database, run the method, check what gets changed/created in the database as a result.
5. Change the implementation: pass in an array of instances. But that's just pushing the problem back by a layer, and a test-driven change which I can't see benefitting the design.

Since I can't really think of a downside for option 4, perhaps that's the answer, but I feel like I need some science to back that up.

Answer (score 0):

I would actually not bother to test it (so your 1.) as the method is really trivial.

If you would like to have it under test coverage though I'd suggest you to use your 3. My reasons are as follows:

- Your test for `.generate_all` just needs to assert that the method `#generate` gets call on every instance returned by `.all`. It this context the actual implementation of `.all` is irrelevant and can be stubbed.
- Your tests for `#generate` should assert that the method does the right thing. If these tests assert the proper functioning of this method, there's no need for the tests for `.generate_all` to duplicate any assertion.
- Testing the proper functioning of `#generate` in the tests for `.generate_all` leads to unnecessary dependencies between the tests.